# Automatic excerpts

Tags: excerpt

How to display excerpts in the homepage instead of full post automatically, without the need to insert `<!--more-->` in every post ?

I tried this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-excerpt/ which or doesn't work or I can't use it.

Here's how I configure it http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-advanced-excerpt-doesnt-work-installed-by-instructions-url-included?replies=1#post-2810718

This is [my website](http://vydunodraugija.lt/).

**I solved the problem using Michael's answer, which made my plugin work.** http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-excerpt/

Comment: To Michael: This worked great, but can you tell me where to go and do if I also want to have the categories with excerpts ? Could it be by adding " and category " to the script <?php if (is_search() || is_home() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search and posts page?> " Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

general:

locate the template for the home page - often index.php - if not see http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

find `the_content()` (possibly with some parameters in the brackets) and change that to `the_excerpt()` - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

specific for Twenty Eleven:

index.php points to the template part content.php;
in content.php edit this line:

`<?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>`

change it to:

`<?php if ( is_search() || is_home() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search and posts page ?>`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: Thanks, it worked.Any ideas how to make an excerpt longer and exclude images ? :)

Comment: @Tomas excerpts don't contain images by default. What you want sounds more like a limited content - you could try something like this: http://bavotasan.com/2009/limiting-the-number-of-words-in-your-excerpt-or-content-in-wordpress/

Comment: instructions how to change the excerpt length are included in http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

Answer (score 0):

Insert this into your functions.php file to control the length of the excerpt by characters NOT words

```
function the_content_limit($max_char, $more_link_text = 'Read more &raquo;', $stripteaser = 0, $more_file = '') {
    $content = get_the_content($more_link_text, $stripteaser, $more_file);
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
    $content = strip_tags($content);

   if (strlen($_GET['p']) > 0) {
      echo "<p>";
      echo $content;
      echo "&nbsp;<a href='";
      the_permalink();
      echo "'>".__("Read more")." &raquo;</a>";
      echo "</p>";
   }
   else if ((strlen($content)>$max_char) && ($espacio = strpos($content, " ", $max_char ))) {
        $content = substr($content, 0, $espacio);
        $content = $content;
        echo "<p>";
        echo $content;
        echo "...";
        echo "&nbsp;<a href='";
        the_permalink();
        echo "'>".$more_link_text."</a>";
        echo "</p>";
   }
   else {
      echo "<p>";
      echo $content;
      echo "&nbsp;<a href='";
      the_permalink();
      echo "'>".__("Read more")." &raquo;</a>";
      echo "</p>";
   }
}
```

Use it in your theme like this

```
<?php the_content_limit(245); ?>
```

Comment: [Do not use `substr()`](http://wpengineer.com/2410/dont-use-strlen/), use `mb_substr()` instead.